# Angular 2 Error "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined" in systemjs-angular-loader.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade

I am trying to use Angular 2 in the same app as Angular 1. To accomplish that I am using the Angular UpgradeModule. To install and set-up TypeScript and Angular 2, I've used the following guide: [Upgrading from AngularJS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#making-angular-dependencies-injectable-to-angularjs).

My Angular 1 version is 1.4.8, Angular is 4.0.3, and TypeScript is 2.3.2.

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "umd",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
"typeRoots": [
  "../../node_modules/@types/"
],
"types": [
  "core-js"
]
},
"compileOnSave": true,
"exclude": [
  "node_modules/*",
  "**/*-aot.ts"
]
}
```

And my systemjs.config.js:

```
(function(global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      "npm:": "/node_modules/"
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the App/Angular2 folder
      app: "/App/Angular2",

      // angular bundles
      "@angular/core": "npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js",
      "@angular/common": "npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js",
      "@angular/compiler": "npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js",
      "@angular/platform-browser":
        "npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":
        "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js",
      "@angular/http": "npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js",
      "@angular/router": "npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js",
      "@angular/forms": "npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js",
      "@angular/upgrade/static":
        "npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js",

      // other libraries
      rxjs: "npm:rxjs",
      "angular-in-memory-web-api":
        "npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js"
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: "js",
        meta: {
          "./*.js": {
            loader: "systemjs-angular-loader.js"
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: "js"
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

I have a main.ts component in the root folder of the project that boostraps the Angular 2 and Angular 1 modules:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { AppModule } from './App/Angular2/app.module';

// This is the entry point for the AngularJS/Angular hybrid application.
// It bootstraps the Angular module 'AppModule' and the AngularJS module 
'mainApp'.
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
    const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
    upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['mainApp']);
});
```

The issue I am having is when I start the application, in Visual Studio 2015, with F5 (or Debug), I get the following error in the developer console of my browser (Chrome):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at systemjs-angular-loader.js

[image: Module is not defined error]

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Do you have github repo to reproduce it?

Comment: @yurzui No, I don't.

Comment: did you try with setting `"module": "commonjs"` in **tsconfig.json** file?

Comment: Yes, i did, but it did not help. I got the same error.